# Manipulating Pandas Series to Give Highest Correlation at Lag of 0

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, cross-correlation

I am trying to align my data so that when I use another comparison method the two data sets are aligned so that they are most similar. So far I have cross-correlated the two Pandas Series and found the lag position for highest correlation. How can I then shift my data to give the a new highest correlation lag position of 0 when the Series are then cross-correlated again.

I have 4 fairly large Pandas Series. One of these Series is a Query to be compared to the other 3 Series and itself.
To find the offset for highest correlation between a query-target series pair, I have used np.correlate() and have calculated the lag position, and  for highest correlation. Having found this lag position I have tried to incorporate this lag into each of the series in order that, once a cross correlation is recalculated, the new lag for highest correlation is now 0. Unfortunately, this has not been very successful.

I feel there are a few ways I could be going wrong in my methodology here, I'm very new to coding, so any pointers will be very much appreciated.

What I Have So Far

Producing a DataFrame containing the original lag positions for highest correlation in each comparison.

```
lags_o = pd.Dataframe({"a":[np.correlate(s4, s1, mode='full').argmax() - np.correlate(s4, s1, mode='full').size/2], 
         "b": [np.correlate(s4, s2, mode='full').argmax() - np.correlate(s4, s2, mode='full').size/2], 
         "c": [np.correlate(s4, s3, mode='full').argmax() - np.correlate(s4, s3, mode='full').size/2], 
         "d": [np.correlate(s4, s4, mode='full').argmax() - np.correlate(s4, s4, mode='full').size/2]})
```

When this is run I get the expected value of 0 for the "d" column, indicating that the two series are optimally aligned (which makes sense). The other columns return non zero values so now i want to incorporate these required shifts into the new cross correlation.

```
# shifting the series by the lag given in lags_o for that comparison
s1_lagged = s1.shift(lags_o["a"].item() 
# selecting all non-NaN values in the series for the next correlation
s1_lagged = s1_lagged[~np.isnan(s1_lagged)]
# this is repeated for the other routes - selecting the appropriate df column
```

What I expected to get back when the query route and the new shifted target series was then passed to the cross-correlation was that each lag position in lags_n would be 0. However, this is not what I am getting at all. Even more confusingly is that the new lag position does not seem to relate to the old lag position (as in the lag does not seem to shift along with the shift imputed into the series). I have tried shifting both the query and target series in turn but have not managed to get the required value.

So my question is how should I correctly manipulate these Series so that i can align these data sets. Happy New Year and thank you for your time and any suggestions you may have.

Comment: you may have an alignement that change over time? i.e. 0 for first 10000 lines, then -100 until 50k. Can you provide a data sample?

Comment: @LudoSchmidt I'm not sure, how would I go about getting the series from my code to here?

Comment: Maybe divide data in 10 period of time.
Then of each period, try to find the optimal lag. You will see if it change over time.

Comment: @LudoSchmidt When you say divide the data into ten time periods then compare them to see if the alignment changes. Surely the alignment will change as i am dealing with a non-repetitive series? have i misunderstood you?